How does the "One Nation One Election" proposal plan to resolve the obvious problem of snap elections?
The Indian government has announced plans for a One Nation One Election (ONOE) scheme.
But there are some obvious questions associated with with it, one of which I list below. How does ONOE claim to solve this problem, if at all?
There will be situations, where the legislature (state assembly or parliament) will not have completed its term, yet government formation would be impossible, necessitating snap elections. This may happen because either the results of the "one" election lead to a hung legislature; or some MLA/MPs defect, causing political instability leading to no one having the majority. If a new election is then proposed, that violates the principle of ONOE. How does ONOE intend to address this problem?
Background (can skip if you already know India's government structure)
India has a federal structure, with a westminster system at both state and national level. While the union government is more powerful, the state governments also have considerable decision making powers. Both levels have a legislature, and the head of the government is elected from amongst the legislature. Each state has its own election cycle based on if the legislature completes its five year term. This federal structure and staggered election cycles per state lead to frequent elections at both national and state levels. This results in recurring administrative challenges, higher election costs, and prolonged periods of the Model Code of Conduct, which impacts governance. The proposal of "One Nation, One Election" seeks to synchronize national and state elections to reduce these inefficiencies, streamline governance, and minimize disruptions. However, this requires constitutional amendments and careful planning to align the election cycles of different states and the union.

I cannot parse the title.

@EmilJeřábek I had missed a verb in there. please see if it makes sense now.

Yes, thank you.

Tried to make the title more readable and added a link to the scheme, revert if you don't like it.

Does anyone even claim it would solve that problem?

proposal is to conduct election across country at a time irrespective of state or national elections. simple!

@MakeStackExchangeGREAT4ever Probably not, because right now the problem does not exist. If a state or territory has an early election, the cycle can simply shift. Under the new scheme this would no longer be possible. Hence why there is a problem to resolve.

This is dealt with in the plans:

holding of a separate election to a Legislative Assembly should be an exception and not the rule

So the plans allow for exceptional situations, such as a hung parliament, to result in a election that is out of sync, but then the elections should be brought back into synchronisation.
For example:
Suppose there are elections in year 1, then the next elections should be held in year 6, and then 11 etc. But if in Tamil Nadu, in year 3, the parliament loses a vote of confidence it must hold exceptional elections out of sync in year 3.  But Tamil Nadu should hold elections again in year 6 to get back into sync, and not wait until five years have passed, in year 8.
The exceptional elections have to happen out of sync, but the plan is for these to be exceptional events and not regular ones.

What is the source of your quote? Is there some official source of the ONOE plan?

Source is https://egazette.gov.in/WriteReadData/2023/248519.pdf  found via the WP link in the OP's question

The idea has varied from not allowing any snap elections to limiting the term of any newly elected government till the next regular cycles of ONE elections.
The "One Nation, One Election" proposal (and propaganda) by the Narendra Modi government is actually a clever subterfuge against indian democracy by the RSS / BJP. (According to the current Modi government, India apparently has "too much democracy").

The world is full of clever answers in search of a genuine question. When talk of One Nation One Election (ONOE) began, it looked like a grand policy solution in search of a real problem. Either a remedy in search of a disease, or a medicine worse than the disease ... It fits into a larger political design that has been in the works for long.
The undeniable fact is that ONOE is not the simple administrative change in the electoral calendar that it is made out to be. It would upset the basic principle of accountability of the executive to the legislature inherent in our parliamentary system of governance ... The proposal to align the tenure of state assemblies as well as municipal and panchayat bodies with Lok Sabha is a violation of the federal principle of governance. In this sense, ONOE seems to be in violation of the “basic structure” of our Constitution ...
At the deepest level, ONOE is a desire to cut down the clutter of democratic politics ... Through an elaborate econometric modeling — elegant in its math but dubious in its assumptions and conclusions — it argues that ONOE would lead to political stability, faster economic growth, predictable policy environment and lower populist pressures ...
Those who dominate the social and economic life of this country are increasingly impatient with its messy politics and have been coming up with one solution after another to “clean” the world of politics ... Certain sections of the political class ... are in sympathy with this reasoning and would like to cut down on the headache of elections, of constantly being on tenterhooks, of the sword of accountability. They can’t do away with elections altogether, but the next best thing is to limit this mess to just once in five years.
(One Nation One Election is a desire to cut down clutter of democratic politics)

The true (ill-) intentions of the RSS / BJP behind this proposal to curtail elections in India is to:

Create the constitutional framework for forced fixed-term legislatures.
Reduce the power of the opposition in public and the legislature.
Consolidation of voter enrolment to create profiles on them and control who votes.
Ensure that future election campaigns can be run in the Presidential form.
Create the political environment for a future theocratic, dictatorship in India.

Point 1 and 2, provides an answer to your question, and was one of the earlier original plan (that has been temporarily shelved amidst the huge opposition to the whole concept).
Under Narendra Modi's "One Nation, One Election" idea, all elections in India are meant to happen within the same time period. Thus, originally it was envisioned that any snap elections cannot be allowed (as that obviously goes against the whole idea of having only ONE election, periodically).
Snap elections in this proposal can be prevented by amending the Indian constitution to allow forced fixed-term legislatures and removing the power to dissolve the legislature (usually done to hold elections). This means that if a government (the executive) loses majority, neither they nor the opposition can demand a new election. Instead, the members of the legislatures will have to explore the formation of a new government with the existing elected members. (Hence the use of the term forced fixed-term legislatures, because a normal fixed-term legislature still has some specific provisions to allow its dissolution and hold elections even before its term. E.g. the Fixed-term Parliaments Act 2011 in the UK)

Addressing the issue of a hung Parliament or Assembly, the proposals suggest a mechanism for resolving situations where no single political party or alliance secures a majority. "A situation that may arise and is required to be dealt with is that of the hung Parliament/Assembly. It is a situation wherein a single political party or a pre-poll alliance does not have enough elected members to secure an overall majority in the House/Assembly," it said.
"The convention over the decades requires the President or the Governor to explore the formation of a Government by inviting the different political parties to form a government, if necessary, by collaborating under a common minimum programme ... (One nation, one election: Kovind panel suggests 18 amendments to Constitution, other statutes)

In such a scenario, it has also been suggested that the power of the opposition to move "no confidence" motion against any government should also be curtailed with the condition that it should also include a "confidence motion" for a new government. In other words, the opposition will not be allowed to move a "no confidence" motion against the existing government until it also has already earned the support to form a new government within the existing legislature. Such a stifling limit on the opposition power gives those in power an upper hand in government formation and preservation and can also create a situation that can allow a government with no majority to still survive and remain in power and rule, which is quite undemocratic.
The idea of forced fixed-term has now (temporarily) evolved to a limited-term proposal. The current idea (according to the Kovind Committee) has been reduced to limiting the term of any new government:

(6) Any loss of confidence (fall of govt.) will need a fresh election, but only for a restricted period (before next cycle of 5 years is triggered). (Everything you need to know about ‘One-Nation-One-election’)

This means that if ONE election is held in 2029, and if any Central or State government falls and a new government is elected in between (for example, in 2032), it will not have the normal 5-year term but will only last till 2034 when the next ONE election cycle will start. (Of course, this negates the whole idea behind holding only ONE election, and, increases the number of elections, and shows the futility behind the whole idea of artificially forcing elections on people).
(More on the drawback on this proposal by a former Law Minister: Modi’s One Election Plan Will Turn India Into Unitary State, Violate Constitution’s Basic Structure. Also a good read: 'Electoral autocracy': The downgrading of India's democracy.)
